# Is there any way to save survey results using SurveyJS as Json or text files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, survey, surveyjs

I'm using SurveyJS to develop web survey. Currently, I was able to make the survey form I wanted to make but struggled to save the data on local computer once I have completed this survey.

Do you have any idea to save the data as json or csv files on local machine?  By using the script below, I could show the result on complete page and now need to save it as file on local.

```
survey
    .onComplete
    .add(function (result) {
        document
            .querySelector('#surveyResult')
            .textContent = "Result JSON:\n" + JSON.stringify(result.data, null, 3);
    });

$("#surveyElement").Survey({model: survey});
```

Please help me this was very stressful for me :(.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this question on how to create and save file on client-side javascript:
[JavaScript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)